# Vertical align element next to responsive image using Bootstrap grid

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

I have a Bootstrap grid of two columns, one col has a responsive image, the second one has a heading, and some other elements. I'd like the content of the second column to always align vertically to the image. Here's the test case:

```css
.align-this {
  //?..
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x600/000/fff">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <div class="align-this">
                    <h1 class="main-title">Title</h1>
                    <p>
                      Description text here. Lorem ipsum or whatever.
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">main cta</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code

```css
.row{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-5 col-md-6 col-lg-7">
                <img class="img-responsive" src="https://dummyimage.com/200x600/000/fff">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-7 col-md-6 col-lg-5">
                <div class="align-this">
                    <h1 class="main-title">Title</h1>
                    <p>
                      Description text here. Lorem ipsum or whatever.
                    </p>
                    <div>
                        <a href="#" class="btn btn-default btn-lg">main cta</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

have a link http://codepen.io/santoshkhalse/pen/oBjZyG

Comment: Thanks. I added a modifier class instead of touching the `row` class.

Comment: Yes! It would be better